# XCode 9.1 cannot clone git bitbucket repo: authorization failed

Tags: xcode, bitbucket

Today I updated my XCode to 9.1 and now I can no longer clone bitbucket repos into XCode.

When I try I get "Authorization failed".

I don't know if it related but also today, when I logged into bitbucket I got a message saying I could not longer log in using my username but had ot use my email address.

Previously I would use this link when cloning a repo into XCode:

https://totsubo@bitbucket.org/totsubo/wordscardsnew.git

XCode then automatically sets my username to 'totsubo', and I cannot change it. I enter my password in the password field but after clicking 'done' XCode gives me an 'Authentication failed' error.

Strangely enough if I put the password into the https link, then XCode is able to clone the repo. (https://totsubo:password@bitbucket.org/totsubo/wordscardsnew.git)

Answer (score 1):

I emailed Atlassian and they suggested re-setting my password. This fixed the issue.